# Use 2 mouse buttons at the same time?

Tags: mouse

I want to bind the pan function to Alt + L Click + R Click, I used to have it bound to Alt + Middle Click, like in Maya, but my carpal tunnel has been getting pretty bad latelly and not having to click the middle mouse button helps a lot.
How can I got about doing that? In the keymap section, blender only accepts one mouse button + modifiers.

Comment: I don't know of any program that allow both, simultaneous MB clicks to imply something, so you may have to investigate some hardware that is designed to your need.   Perhaps try a tablet input device?  My best wishes.